# Is there a way to auto mount SMB storage without nobrowse option?

Tags: macos, finder, mount, smb, automount

I want to create an permanent SMB mount and read SMB storage in Finder. So I read following articles.

[Create a Permanent SMB Mount in OSX (Updated)](http://www.dforge.net/2012/08/07/create-a-permanent-smb-mount-in-osx/)

[Automounting NFS share in OS X into /Volumes](https://gist.github.com/lawrencealan/8697518)

After that, auto mounting SMB storage has worked properly. But Finder can't read the storage because of nobrowse option which I didn't set. Is there a way to auto mount SMB storage without nobrowse option?

The details are as follows.

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.4
BuildVersion:   13E28
$ sudo sh -c "echo '/- auto_smb -nodev,nosuid' >> /etc/auto_master"
$ sudo sh -c "echo '/../Volumes/share -fstype=smbfs,soft ://user:password@ipaddress/share' >> /etc/auto_smb"
$ sudo automount -vc
$ mount | grep smbfs
//user@ipaddress/share on /Volumes/share (smbfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse, mounted by tommy)
```

Comment: I have this problem too.

Comment: I'm seeing this intermittently, in Yosemite. Haven't yet found a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried adding `-nosuid` so it says: /- auto_smb -nosuid

Answer (score 1):

Edit to `FALSE` and remove the `#` in the following line in **/etc/autofs.cfg**:
`#AUTOMOUNTD_NOBROWSE=TRUE`